# Add a new page to WordPress using a plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

How does a plugin add a page to the current WordPress theme a given URL?

Sample URL: `http://wordpress/plugin-name/start`

This page should display a form using that utilizes the current theme.

At the end of the day I'm going to replace the current front-facing WordPress login and registration mechanisms with a custom implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to hook a function to the `template_redirect` action.

There, you can recognize the special URL(s) you want and then you can load your own template accordingly.

To make it use the existing theme, you can do similar things like a theme would, such as call `get_header()`, `get_footer()`, `get_sidebar()`, etc.

After you've output your page, you'll need to explicitly call `exit();` to prevent the normal page output from occurring.

Note: In WordPress 3.0, a better way is to hook to the `template_include` filter, and have it return the file-include-path to your own template file.

This doesn't require the `exit();`, so it's more compatible with other plugins.