# Create a wp plugin

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to make a wordpress plugin that creates a page and a widget, the widget that would have a form and send it to the page (POST), and that this shows the response to the submitted values​​.
I do know the widget + / -, the page is not, because not found anything that speaks to that.

Does anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question about creating a page from within a plugin?

[Wordpress plugin - add a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512019/wordpress-plugin-add-a-new-page)

Not to say that it's a bad idea, there's plenty of good reasons to create the page... but just be sure yours requires that. A lot of the time, creating a shortcode for your widget's content to display is not only easier to program, but gives the user more flexibility in how they display your content.

Comment: thx for helkp, but the answer not response to mine answer. basically I want to know is how to create a page using a plugin